# Google App Engine Storing Dynamic java Objects

Tags: java, google-app-engine, object, dynamic, google-cloud-datastore

I have a few questions about google app engine / datastore and storing dynamic objects.

First here is some background information on my project.  I would like to add this feature to my current java app engine site:  I would like to have customers that make custom forms and store data from those forms into datastore.  Now the forms have a few common elements like textarea, drop-down menus, text areas, and file upload boxes.  They can also add check boxes and change permissions of that object to the clients they have under their management.

What my main questions are is what is the best way to store this data with datastore?  Is there any way that I can have one object that encompasses all the posibilities?

Or should I look into finding a way to dynamically allocating an object and placing it into the data store?  One problem with this might be keeping generated bytecode with subsequent uploads.

Any ideas and/or incites into this problem will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [the low-level API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/package-summary.html) you can have one object that contains all the data. All the fields end up being properties in an [Entity](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity.html). For the files you should of course use [the BlobStore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/package-summary.html) API.